# Scraping web site

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 page = requests.get("https://www.marca.com/futbol/primera/equipos.html")
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 equipos = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'id':'nombreEquipo'})

 aux = []
 for equipo in equipos:
     aux.append(equipo)
```

If i do print(aux[0]) i got this:
     , 
     
     Villarreal

Entrenador:

Javier Calleja

Jugadores:

**1** Sergio     Asenjo

**13** Andrés Fernández

**25** Mariano Barbosa

...

And my problem is i want to take the tag:

```
 <h2 class="cintillo">Villarreal</h2>
```

And the tag:

**1** Sergio     Asenjo

And put it into a bataBase
How can i take that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the first `<h2 class="cintillo">` element from `equipo` like this:

```
h2 = str(equipo.find('h2', {'class':'cintillo'}))
```

If you only want the inner HTML (without any tags), use:

```
h2 = equipo.find('h2', {'class':'cintillo'}).text
```

And you can extract all the `<span class="dorsal-jugador">` elements from `equipo` like this:

```
jugadores = equipo.find_all('span', {'class':'dorsal-jugador'})
```

Then append `h2` and `jugadores` to a multi-dimensional list.

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.marca.com/futbol/primera/equipos.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
equipos = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'id':'nombreEquipo'})

aux = []
for equipo in equipos:
        h2 = equipo.find('h2', {'class':'cintillo'}).text
        jugadores = equipo.find_all('span', {'class':'dorsal-jugador'})
        aux.append([h2,[j.text for j in jugadores]])

# format list for printing
print('\n\n'.join(['--'+i[0]+'--\n' + '\n'.join(i[1])  for i in aux]))
```

Output sample:

```
--Alavés--
Fernando Pacheco
Antonio Sivera
Álex Domínguez
Carlos Vigaray
...
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55550385

Comment: Thanks, its a good idea but i need to save in equipo all the player like: Alaves- fernando pacheco antonio sivera alex....

Comment: @RAZVANLISMANU I updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary of team names as keys with lists of [entrenador, players ] as values

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.marca.com/futbol/primera/equipos.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

teams = {}

for team in soup.select('[id=nombreEquipo]'):
    team_name = team.select_one('.cintillo').text 
    entrenador = team.select_one('dd').text
    players = [item.text for item in team.select('.dorsal-jugador')]
    teams[team_name] = {entrenador : players}
print(teams)
```